# Using bytemessage instead of objectMessage in JMS

Tags: java, json, performance, jakarta-ee, jms

I am using JMS in my archtiecure in many ways.

Latency and performance are very big factor in our architecure.

Ive read that using jms with ObjectMessage in order to pass whole java object within the message takes lots of performances.

Alternative solution is converting to json,protobuff and having the message being sent as a bytemessage/text message.

Could you please make this clear for me:

1. in case I choose  json. after converting from String to json should I send the message
     as test or as ByteArray? (any difference?)
2. Is the the total time of converting String to json from the sender side and
   vice versa on the consumer side will be less/more then just sending ObjectMessage?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my 2 cents

1) IMO , you should send the data in String using TextMessage and  have it deserialized into Json Object.
    I cant tell you the exact performance stats , but i guess the Serialization is better than Marshalling , as its less overhead when you reconstruct it to object.

[Comparing Marshalling with serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29#Comparison_with_serialization)

2)Moreover , just by avoiding sending the data as a Object Stream, 
 the message can be received and processed by a non-java based Message Solution

From [Java Dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/marshalling-unmarshalling-java)

> A big downside of Externalizable is that you have to maintain this
>   logic yourself – if you add, remove or change a field in your class,
>   you have to change your writeExternal/readExternal methods to account
>   for it.

Comment: So you saying basically I should do it via TextMessage and not BytesArrays?